# BiqQuery GEOGRAPHY clustering column - max limit 1024 bytes?

Tags: google-bigquery

The [BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data) say:

> If you store GEOGRAPHY data in a table and your queries filter data by using a spatial predicate, ensure that the table is clustered by the GEOGRAPHY column.

But only `POINT` types would be smaller than 1kb, most geographies are much larger. So when I go to insert a geography into a clustered column, I get this error:

```
Clustering encountered a key Msg_0_CLOUD_QUERY_TABLE.geom that is 1995 bytes long, which is more than the maximum allowed length of 1024 bytes.
```

Is the max size for a GEOGRAPHY clustered column really 1024 bytes? Do I need to insert my data differently somehow?

Comment: Could you please file a bug using https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers and describe specific details how you get this error? Do you insert data using LOAD job, streaming insert, or SQL INSERT command?

Comment: Tried with both FILE_LOADS and streaming. Seems like it is not a bug though, just an expectation mismatch, since BQ docs state that clustered columns have a 1kb limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE Jan 2021**: I was informed by the Bigquery team that the 1kb limit was not intentional, and they are working on a fix so that arbitrary-size geometries can be clustered without generating a surrogate bounding box.

This looks like the real limit, so I pre-computed centroids for my polygons using GDAL in Dataflow, stored them in a separate column, and clustered on the centroid geography. Works great.

Comment: The limit has been removed. Indeed, it was not intentional, and was caused by mixup of STRING / BYTES vs GEOGRAPHY datatypes. BTW, the limit was also removed from STRING / BYTES types, however only first 1k characters of the STRING / BYTES are considered for clustering.